# Each time I boot into Arch Linux I must use the terminal to connect to a network. How can I fix this?

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager

I recently installed Arch Linux and am having issues getting the network manager set up. I am able to `sudo wifi-menu` and connect to a router, but these settings are not preserved through a reboot.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You *aren't* setting up NetworkManager; `wifi-menu` comes from "netctl" and it doesn't automatically configure its generated netctl profiles to start on boot.

From your question I assume you have NetworkManager installed. To use it,

1. start it:

   ```
   systemctl start NetworkManager
   ```
2. make it auto-start on boot:

   ```
   systemctl enable NetworkManager
   ```
3. tell it to connect to a WiFi network:

   ```
   nmcli dev wifi con "My network"
   ```

---

However, if you actually meant *netctl* by "the network manager", enable the `netctl-auto` service:

```
systemctl enable netctl-auto@wl…
```

(Replace `wl…` with the actual interface name that you see in `ip link`.)

Comment: I was connected to the network prior to the issuing the first command you have listed. After executing that instruction I was disconnected and could not reconnect; I had to reboot the system. I am going to try it again as soon as I finish upgrading packages per your answer to my other question.